# Undefined Property Nested JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to grab a values from this nested object. Seems that the syntax is fine for the object. What am I missing?

```
console.log(thePosts['THE PARENT ONE']['sections']['ONE SECTION']['subs']['img'][3]);

window.thePosts = {}
window.thePosts = {
    'THE PARENT ONE' : {
        'url':'the-url',
        'sections': [{
            'ONE SECTION' : {
                'url':'making-money',
                'subs': [
                    {'_id:':'1','title': 'title 1','img': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                    {'_id:':'1','title': 'title 2','img': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                    {'_id:':'1','title': 'title 3','img': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                    {'_id:':'1','title': 'title 4','img': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
                ]
            },
            'TWO SECTION' : {
                'url':'marketing',
                'subs': [
                    {'_id:':'1','title': 'title 1','img': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                    {'_id:':'1','title': 'title 2','img': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                    {'_id:':'1','title': 'title 3','img': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'},
                    {'_id:':'1','title': 'title 4','img': '<img src="/wp-content/assets/images/pop1.jpg">'}
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: I am guessing you meant `['subs'][3]['img']`?

Comment: `thePosts['THE PARENT ONE']['sections']` is an array of objects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
thePosts['THE PARENT ONE']['sections'][0]['ONE SECTION']['subs'][3]['img']
```

`sections` and `subs` are both arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`sections` is an array:

```
thePosts['THE PARENT ONE']['sections'][0]['ONE SECTION']['subs'][3]['img']
                                       ^                         ^----^
```